# Does What I've Proved Imply the Irrationality of $\pi$?

Tags: number-theory

I can prove that if r is real and s is nonzero integer, then given the numbers
$\sin (r / s), \sin ((r-1) / s), \cos (r / s), \cos ((r-1) / s)$
 at least one is irrational.
does this have anything to do with the proof of $\pi$'s irrationality?
I well know that the irrationality of sines with rational arguments implies the irrationality of $\pi$. Please help me, I have been trying for a long time to prove the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: You could just say one of $\sin(x)$, $\sin(x+1/n)$, $\cos(x)$, $\cos(x + 1/n)$ is irrational. Let $x = 0$, then at least one of $\sin(1/n)$ or $\cos(1/n)$ is irrational. OTOH, the result is no stronger than this; if all four  were rational for some real $x$ then, by the double angle formulas, so would be $\sin(1/n)$ and $\cos(1/n)$. You can prove directly that one of these numbers is irrational; otherwise $\sin(1/n) + i \cos(1/n) \in \mathbf{Q}(i)$, then (taking $n$th powers) so is $\sin(1) + i \cos(1)$. Thus $\sin(1) \in \mathbf{Q}$ but the irrationality proof of $e$ applies here as well.

Comment: All of which is to say that this is not yet enough to prove that $\pi$ is irrational. After all, at least one of $\sin(x)$, $\sin(x + (\pi/4)/n)$, $\cos(x)$, $\cos(x + (\pi/4)/n)$ is irrational too.

Comment: The irrationality of pi was not proven until 1761. Whether or not the sines or cosines of some numbers are rational may tell you something about whether some  of those numbers are rational multiples of pi,but won't tell you anything about pi itself. See "Proof That Pi Is Irrational" in Wikipedia.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet if you could prove that at least one of $\sin(m/n)$ or $\cos(m/n)$ is irrational for all integers $n,m \ne 0$ you prove that $\pi/2$ is irrational as well. At the moment, the OP only has enough to prove that $\pi/2 \ne 1/n$, or that $2/\pi$ is not an integer. Of course, there are alternative approaches to proving this result.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

You can use the fact that

$$\tan(x)\in \Bbb Q \implies x\in \Bbb R-\Bbb Q$$

Comment: This fact seems to be more complex than proving that $\pi$ is irrational, since $\tan(\pi)=0$. In other words this fact would immediately imply that $\pi$ is irrational, so the proof of this fact has a difficulty level that is either the same or larger than the proof that $\pi$ is irrational.